# Position Angular UI Datepicker Outside Scrollbar

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a datepicker inside a scroll container. Problem is that when it appears it is confined within the scrollbar and messes up the height of the scrollbar,  I want the popup to appear outside/in-front of the scroll nice and smooth, so causing no height issues.

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4ht8y4nw/111/)

```
<div ng-controller="DatepickerDemoCtrl">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="input-group">
          <input
            type="text"
            id="popup"
            class="form-control"
            datepicker-popup=""
            ng-model="today"
            is-open="opened"
            min-date="minDate"
            max-date="'2015-06-22'"
            ng-click="open()"/>
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <label for="popup" class="btn btn-default"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></label>
          </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<pre>Selected date is: <em>{{today}}</em></pre>
```

```
body {padding:20px}
.col-md-6{
    overflow:scroll;
    height:200px;
    background:red;
    }
.input-group{
    background:green;
    height:300px;
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4ht8y4nw/111/

Comment: put in a little code so you can add the fiddle link properly in the question.

Comment: Thats funny, adding code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the appendToBody to true.

```js
.constant('datepickerPopupConfig', {
  datepickerPopup: "MMM d, yyyy",
  closeOnDateSelection: true,
  appendToBody: fasle,
  showButtonBar: false
})
```

Comment: Thanks, Is there any way close the popup on scroll. It just stays there.

Answer (score 0):

Along with changing `appendToBody: true` in ui-bootstrap.js, I had to change the `z-index` value to `1051`

```js
// ui-bootstrap.js
.constant('uibDatepickerPopupConfig', {
    appendToBody: true
)}
```

```css
.uib-datepicker-popup.dropdown-menu {
    z-index: 1051 !important;
}
```